# How to add object to a list after each getter (how to repeat similar logic in getters)

Tags: python, python-2.7, repeat, getter

```
# Message Object Creation File
messageList = []

def getMessageObjectA():
    msg = MessageCreator(msgAttribute1, msgAttribute2)
    msgList.append(msg)
    return msg

def getMessageObjectB():
    msg = MessageCreator(msgAttribute3, msgAttribute4)
    msgList.append(msg)
    return msg

def getMessageObjectC():
    msg = MessageCreator(msgAttribute5, msgAttribute6)
    msgList.append(msg)
    return msg

def clearMessages():
    for msg in messageList:
        # logic to clear messages
```

```
# Test Script #1
import MessageObjects as MsgObj

a = MsgObj.getMessageObjectA()
c = MsgObj.getMessageObjectC()

# Do stuff

MsgObj.clearMessages()

# Do more stuff
```

```
# Test Script #223423423
import MessageObjects as MsgObj

e = MsgObj.getMessageObjectE()
u = MsgObj.getMessageObjectU()
y = MsgObj.getMessageObjectY()

# Do stuff

MsgObj.clearMessages()

# Do more stuff
```

In the actual code, I will have over a hundred getMessageObject() functions. And in certain places, I will only call some of those getMessageObject() functions depending on what is needed, which is why I have those getters.

Adding this line `msgList.append(msg)` inside every function introduces human programming error and possibly unnecessarily adds to the length of the source code file.

How do I have every getter call `msgList.append(msg)`? Is there some sort of fancy way to wrap all of this logic in a wrapper function that I'm not thinking of? I'm pretty sure decorators won't work because they don't see the variables inside the function, and I would have to repeat those decorators too for every function I make.

NOTE: Answer has to be in Python2. Can't use Python3 at work.

NOTE: The intent is for these getters() to be inside a Constants-like file, where our many different test scripts call these getters.

Comment: Yes, that's the difference. And they're decided by what kind of item it is. In particular, what kind of "message object" it is. So, yes, there would be cause for programmer error, but hopefully I don't mess that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to generalize the function. The only difference between each `getItem#` function is the arguments passed to `GenerateItem`. Just pass that data in to `getItem`:

```
def getItem(arg1, arg2):
    item = GenerateItem(arg1, arg2)
    itemList.append(item)
    return item

a = getItem(val1, val2)
b = getItem(val3, val4)
```

If you need functions with specific names, just create aliases. This can be done easily using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

getItemA = partial(getItem, val1, val2)
getItemB = partial(getItem, val3, val4)

a = getItemA()
b = getItemB()
```

The arguments are `partial`ly applied to `getItem`, and a 0-arity function is returned and placed in the alias.

Of course though, manually hardcoding all these also leads to sources of error. You may want to reconsider how things are setup if this is necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I should specify that the the getters() are going to be in a Constants-like file, where all of our many test scripts call these getters.

Comment: I think that solution works, let me give it a shot.

Comment: See my edited question too for more clarification on what I was asking, but the solution works! Thank you!!!!

Comment: @FridaySky Honestly, I have to have a nap before I go to a concert later tonight. If this solution needs to be refined, I can help with that in a couple hours/tomorrow.

Comment: Think it works great. I was mostly wondering what you meant by "Of course though, manually hardcoding all these also leads to sources of error. You may want to reconsider how things are setup if this is necessary." As in, I think the way the framework is setup (as shown in the question) is probably the best we can do. This is actually better than the previous framework where we were instantiating every single MessageCreator object in existence.

Comment: @FridaySky I would zip all your message attributes into a list of pairs, then iterate over the list, create the partial functions, then add them to a list/dictionary of functions for the test code to use. That way, you can automate the creation of the functions instead of needing to manually hardcode them.

Answer (score 0):

Why should the `itemList` be populated inside getters in the first place?

What you can do is, when you are calling such getters, add a line for the appending the respective item to the list

```
a = getItemA()
itemList.append(a)
```

Comment: We ALWAYS want to add the item (message) to the list, so that we can clear all the messages later.